# Is there a proof for the primitive element theorem for perfect fields? (Not for fields of characteristic zero necessarily)

Tags: field-theory

Is there a proof for the primitive element theorem for perfect fields? (not for fields of characteristic zero necessarily)

For fields of characteristic zero and also finite fields of characteristic $p$ there are classic proofs. I am looking for for perfect infinite fields of characteristic $p$.

Does anybody know?

Comment: The primitive element theorem implies that if $E/F$ is a finite separable extension then it admits a primitive element. If $F$ is perfect any finite extension is separable.

Comment: @Pedro: this is not an answer to the OP’s question. If the OP has only seen proofs in characteristic zero and for finite fields then the OP has not seen a proof in the generality you stated the theorem and wants one.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Agreed. To clarify: the general primitive element theorem says that $E/F$ admits such an element iff it admits only finitely many intermediate extensions. I think a proof of this is available in Jacobson's *Basic Algebra*.

Comment: Search "primitive element theorem proof", I like [thisone](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~kbrown/6310/primitive.pdf).

Comment: How about for infinite perfect fields of characteristic p? 
@Pedro